# Find and match attributes from separate inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a `.sub-list` radio, I need to get the `.cat-item` color that matches the `[data-for]` on the `.sub-list` item and `fill` the `<svg>` and `<b>` of the checked item.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='radios']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {}
  });
});
```

```css
.cat1 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.cat2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-item">
  Main Category:
  <div class="cat-dropdown closed">
    <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="cat-list" id="category">
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
          <input type="radio" name="cat1">
          Main 1
        </label>
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
          <input type="radio" name="cat2">
          Main 2
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Sub Category:
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="type-list">
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="comp">
            <input class="sub-input" id="comp" type="radio" name="radios" />
            <span class="sub-icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25">
                <path id="" fill="silver" d="M21.72 16.784a.094.094 0 0 0-.071-.033H3.351a.094.094 0 0 0-.093.108c.003.017.279 1.711 2.421 1.711h13.642c2.142 0 2.418-1.694 2.42-1.711a.095.095 0 0 0-.021-.075zm-7.844 1.193h-2.752v-.633h2.752v.633zM5.252 16.092h14.496c.21 0 .38-.17.38-.38V6.81a.38.38 0 0 0-.38-.38H5.252a.38.38 0 0 0-.38.38v8.904c0 .21.17.38.38.38zM6.2 7.758h12.598v7.006H6.201V7.758z"/>
              </svg><br>
              <b>Main 1A</b>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="ticket">
            <input class="sub-input" id="ticket" type="radio" name="radios" />
            <span class="sub-icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25">
                <path id="" fill="silver" d="M7.519 14.008l3.473 3.473 6.372-6.372-3.473-3.473-6.372 6.372zm13.884-4.77L19.925 7.76a1.98 1.98 0 0 1-2.686-2.686l-1.477-1.477a.992.992 0 0 0-1.4 0L3.597 14.362a.992.992 0 0 0 0 1.4l1.478 1.478a1.98 1.98 0 0 1 2.685 2.686l1.478 1.477a.993.993 0 0 0 1.4 0l10.765-10.765a.993.993 0 0 0 0-1.4zM10.992 19.07L5.93 14.008l7.962-7.96 5.06 5.061-7.96 7.96z"/>
              </svg><br>
              <b>Main 1B</b>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="elephant">
            <input class="sub-input" id="elephant" type="radio" name="radios" />
            <span class="sub-icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25">
                <path id="" fill="silver" d="M19.565 9.341h-4.086a4.636 4.636 0 0 1-1.67 3.027.476.476 0 0 1-.672-.067.478.478 0 0 1 .066-.674 3.684 3.684 0 0 0 1.354-2.858 3.7 3.7 0 0 0-3.695-3.695A3.7 3.7 0 0 0 7.188 8.38a3.448 3.448 0 0 0-.86.702c-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.029.029-.115.117-.422.117a.957.957 0 1 0 0 1.914c.74 0 1.343-.234 1.793-.696.6-.617.795-1.505.846-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.211 1.325 1.211h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.96h4.544v1.975c0 .672.565 1.195 1.237 1.195h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.182c.598-.3.957-.898.957-1.586v-3.828c0-.99-.783-1.794-1.774-1.794zM7.189 12.107a.451.451 0 1 1 .902 0 .451.451 0 0 1-.902 0z"/>
              </svg><br>
              <b>Main 2A</b>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="hook">
            <input class="sub-input" id="hook" type="radio" name="radios" />
            <span class="sub-icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25">
                <path id="" fill="silver" d="M13.587 16.6h1.829c-.254 1.303-1.405 2.31-2.772 2.31a2.836 2.836 0 0 1-2.823-2.836v-5.166a.853.853 0 0 0 .25-.611V5.884a.779.779 0 0 0-.776-.793.779.779 0 0 0-.776.793v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.611v5.166c0 2.115 1.74 3.835 3.854 3.835 2.09 0 3.821-1.717 3.846-3.83l.012-1.97v-1.573L13.587 16.6z"/>
              </svg><br>
              <b>Main 2B</b>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete what exactly have you tried to get that to get to this and fill that up. That's how it sounds to me, gibberish. Without the attempt to try, you are just asking for others to give you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is painful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='radios']").change(function() {
    // Reset hardcoded styles for previously checked item
    // Just do them all
    allSpans = $("input[name='radios']").siblings('span')
    allSpans.children('b').css('color', 'black')
    allSpans.find('[fill]').css('fill', 'silver')

    // Find cat and color
    list = $(this).closest('.sub-list')
    catName = list.attr('data-for')
    cat = $('.cat-list').find('.cat-item:has([name="' + catName + '"])')

    var color = cat.css('color')
    
    // Set values
    list.find('svg [fill]').css('fill', color)
    $('b', list).css('color', color)
  });
});
```

```css
.cat1 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.cat2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-item">
  Main Category:
  <div class="cat-dropdown closed">
    <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="cat-list" id="category">
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
<input type="radio" name="cat1">Main 1</label>
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
<input type="radio" name="cat2">Main 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Sub Category:
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="type-list">
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="comp">
<input class="sub-input" id="comp" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" fill="silver" d="M21.72 16.784a.094.094 0 0 0-.071-.033H3.351a.094.094 0 0 0-.093.108c.003.017.279 1.711 2.421 1.711h13.642c2.142 0 2.418-1.694 2.42-1.711a.095.095 0 0 0-.021-.075zm-7.844 1.193h-2.752v-.633h2.752v.633zM5.252 16.092h14.496c.21 0 .38-.17.38-.38V6.81a.38.38 0 0 0-.38-.38H5.252a.38.38 0 0 0-.38.38v8.904c0 .21.17.38.38.38zM6.2 7.758h12.598v7.006H6.201V7.758z"/></svg><br><b>Main 1A</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="ticket">
<input class="sub-input" id="ticket" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" fill="silver" d="M7.519 14.008l3.473 3.473 6.372-6.372-3.473-3.473-6.372 6.372zm13.884-4.77L19.925 7.76a1.98 1.98 0 0 1-2.686-2.686l-1.477-1.477a.992.992 0 0 0-1.4 0L3.597 14.362a.992.992 0 0 0 0 1.4l1.478 1.478a1.98 1.98 0 0 1 2.685 2.686l1.478 1.477a.993.993 0 0 0 1.4 0l10.765-10.765a.993.993 0 0 0 0-1.4zM10.992 19.07L5.93 14.008l7.962-7.96 5.06 5.061-7.96 7.96z"/></svg><br><b>Main 1B</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="elephant">
<input class="sub-input" id="elephant" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" fill="silver" d="M19.565 9.341h-4.086a4.636 4.636 0 0 1-1.67 3.027.476.476 0 0 1-.672-.067.478.478 0 0 1 .066-.674 3.684 3.684 0 0 0 1.354-2.858 3.7 3.7 0 0 0-3.695-3.695A3.7 3.7 0 0 0 7.188 8.38a3.448 3.448 0 0 0-.86.702c-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.029.029-.115.117-.422.117a.957.957 0 1 0 0 1.914c.74 0 1.343-.234 1.793-.696.6-.617.795-1.505.846-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.211 1.325 1.211h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.96h4.544v1.975c0 .672.565 1.195 1.237 1.195h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.182c.598-.3.957-.898.957-1.586v-3.828c0-.99-.783-1.794-1.774-1.794zM7.189 12.107a.451.451 0 1 1 .902 0 .451.451 0 0 1-.902 0z"/></svg><br><b>Main 2A</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="hook">
<input class="sub-input" id="hook" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" fill="silver" d="M13.587 16.6h1.829c-.254 1.303-1.405 2.31-2.772 2.31a2.836 2.836 0 0 1-2.823-2.836v-5.166a.853.853 0 0 0 .25-.611V5.884a.779.779 0 0 0-.776-.793.779.779 0 0 0-.776.793v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.611v5.166c0 2.115 1.74 3.835 3.854 3.835 2.09 0 3.821-1.717 3.846-3.83l.012-1.97v-1.573L13.587 16.6z"/></svg><br><b>Main 2B</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS only:

```css
.cat1 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.cat2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

svg {
  fill: silver;
}

/* This doesn't cascade, previous svg rule is more specific */
.sub-item.cat1 input[name="radios"]:checked+span,
.sub-item.cat1 input[name="radios"]:checked+span svg {
  color: blue;
  fill: blue;
}

.sub-item.cat2 input[name="radios"]:checked+span,
.sub-item.cat2 input[name="radios"]:checked+span svg {
  color: red;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-item">
  Main Category:
  <div class="cat-dropdown closed">
    <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="cat-list" id="category">
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
<input type="radio" name="cat1">Main 1</label>
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
<input type="radio" name="cat2">Main 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Sub Category:
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="type-list">
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="comp">
<input class="sub-input" id="comp" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" d="M21.72 16.784a.094.094 0 0 0-.071-.033H3.351a.094.094 0 0 0-.093.108c.003.017.279 1.711 2.421 1.711h13.642c2.142 0 2.418-1.694 2.42-1.711a.095.095 0 0 0-.021-.075zm-7.844 1.193h-2.752v-.633h2.752v.633zM5.252 16.092h14.496c.21 0 .38-.17.38-.38V6.81a.38.38 0 0 0-.38-.38H5.252a.38.38 0 0 0-.38.38v8.904c0 .21.17.38.38.38zM6.2 7.758h12.598v7.006H6.201V7.758z"/></svg><br><b>Main 1A</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat1">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="ticket">
<input class="sub-input" id="ticket" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" d="M7.519 14.008l3.473 3.473 6.372-6.372-3.473-3.473-6.372 6.372zm13.884-4.77L19.925 7.76a1.98 1.98 0 0 1-2.686-2.686l-1.477-1.477a.992.992 0 0 0-1.4 0L3.597 14.362a.992.992 0 0 0 0 1.4l1.478 1.478a1.98 1.98 0 0 1 2.685 2.686l1.478 1.477a.993.993 0 0 0 1.4 0l10.765-10.765a.993.993 0 0 0 0-1.4zM10.992 19.07L5.93 14.008l7.962-7.96 5.06 5.061-7.96 7.96z"/></svg><br><b>Main 1B</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="elephant">
<input class="sub-input" id="elephant" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" d="M19.565 9.341h-4.086a4.636 4.636 0 0 1-1.67 3.027.476.476 0 0 1-.672-.067.478.478 0 0 1 .066-.674 3.684 3.684 0 0 0 1.354-2.858 3.7 3.7 0 0 0-3.695-3.695A3.7 3.7 0 0 0 7.188 8.38a3.448 3.448 0 0 0-.86.702c-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.029.029-.115.117-.422.117a.957.957 0 1 0 0 1.914c.74 0 1.343-.234 1.793-.696.6-.617.795-1.505.846-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.211 1.325 1.211h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.96h4.544v1.975c0 .672.565 1.195 1.237 1.195h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.182c.598-.3.957-.898.957-1.586v-3.828c0-.99-.783-1.794-1.774-1.794zM7.189 12.107a.451.451 0 1 1 .902 0 .451.451 0 0 1-.902 0z"/></svg><br><b>Main 2A</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-item cat2">
        <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
          <label class="sub-btn" for="hook">
<input class="sub-input" id="hook" type="radio" name="radios" />
<span class="sub-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path id="" d="M13.587 16.6h1.829c-.254 1.303-1.405 2.31-2.772 2.31a2.836 2.836 0 0 1-2.823-2.836v-5.166a.853.853 0 0 0 .25-.611V5.884a.779.779 0 0 0-.776-.793.779.779 0 0 0-.776.793v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.611v5.166c0 2.115 1.74 3.835 3.854 3.835 2.09 0 3.821-1.717 3.846-3.83l.012-1.97v-1.573L13.587 16.6z"/></svg><br><b>Main 2B</b></span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear, the main cat radio's are independent. Only the sub radio's should change color to match the cat-item when they are checked.

Comment: So each sub-item belongs to a main cat-item (which has the color). So if one of the sub-items is checked, it takes the color of the main cat-item it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The color is dynamic so it needs to be in the HTML markup. Your jQuery solution works well

Comment: @KyleUnderhill I just edited out a couple repeated lines.

Answer (score 0):

when radio is changed(clicked), find its nearest label color and apply the color to the elements you want.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cat-list input[type='radio']").change(function(){
          var
          theGrey = '#ccc',
          theTextColor = $(this).closest('label').css("color"),
          theCat=$(this).val();
          console.log(theCat+theTextColor);
          $('.sub-item').css('border-color', theGrey);
          $('.'+theCat).css('border-color', theTextColor);
          $('b').css('color', '#000');
          $('.'+theCat+' b').css('color', theTextColor);
          $('.sub-icon svg path').css('fill', theGrey);
          $('.'+theCat + ' .sub-icon svg path').css('fill', theTextColor);


});
      })
    </script>
    <style media="screen">
      .cat1 {
        border: 2px solid ;
      }

      .cat2 {
        border: 2px solid ;
      }
      .sub-item{border-color:#ccc; margin-bottom: 5px;}

      .text-color-1{}
      .text-color-2{}
    </style>
    <div class="post-item">
      <form action="">

      Main Category:
      <div class="cat-dropdown closed">
        <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
            <div class="cat-list" id="category">
              <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
                <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat1">Main 1</label>
              <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
                <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat2">Main 2</label>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      Sub Category:
      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="type-list">
          <div class="sub-item cat1">
            <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
              <label class="sub-btn" for="comp">
                <input class="sub-input" id="comp" type="radio" name="radios"/>
                <span class="sub-icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path
                    id=""
                    fill="silver"
                    d="M21.72 16.784a.094.094 0 0 0-.071-.033H3.351a.094.094 0 0 0-.093.108c.003.017.279 1.711 2.421 1.711h13.642c2.142 0 2.418-1.694 2.42-1.711a.095.095 0 0 0-.021-.075zm-7.844 1.193h-2.752v-.633h2.752v.633zM5.252 16.092h14.496c.21 0 .38-.17.38-.38V6.81a.38.38 0 0 0-.38-.38H5.252a.38.38 0 0 0-.38.38v8.904c0 .21.17.38.38.38zM6.2 7.758h12.598v7.006H6.201V7.758z"/></svg><br>
                  <b>Main 1A</b></span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item cat1">
            <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat1">
              <label class="sub-btn" for="ticket">
                <input class="sub-input" id="ticket" type="radio" name="radios"/>
                <span class="sub-icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path
                    id=""
                    fill="silver"
                    d="M7.519 14.008l3.473 3.473 6.372-6.372-3.473-3.473-6.372 6.372zm13.884-4.77L19.925 7.76a1.98 1.98 0 0 1-2.686-2.686l-1.477-1.477a.992.992 0 0 0-1.4 0L3.597 14.362a.992.992 0 0 0 0 1.4l1.478 1.478a1.98 1.98 0 0 1 2.685 2.686l1.478 1.477a.993.993 0 0 0 1.4 0l10.765-10.765a.993.993 0 0 0 0-1.4zM10.992 19.07L5.93 14.008l7.962-7.96 5.06 5.061-7.96 7.96z"/></svg><br>
                  <b>Main 1B</b></span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item cat2">
            <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
              <label class="sub-btn" for="elephant">
                <input class="sub-input" id="elephant" type="radio" name="radios"/>
                <span class="sub-icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path
                    id=""
                    fill="silver"
                    d="M19.565 9.341h-4.086a4.636 4.636 0 0 1-1.67 3.027.476.476 0 0 1-.672-.067.478.478 0 0 1 .066-.674 3.684 3.684 0 0 0 1.354-2.858 3.7 3.7 0 0 0-3.695-3.695A3.7 3.7 0 0 0 7.188 8.38a3.448 3.448 0 0 0-.86.702c-.826.936-1.008 2.16-1.008 3.053 0 .382.01.765.02 1.135.03 1.11.066 2.493-.3 2.87-.029.029-.115.117-.422.117a.957.957 0 1 0 0 1.914c.74 0 1.343-.234 1.793-.696.6-.617.795-1.505.846-2.513.113.003.234.005.36.005.955 0 2.245-.115 3.266-.627 0 0-.07.442-.07.568v3.807c0 .68.643 1.211 1.325 1.211h.018c.682 0 1.23-.53 1.23-1.21v-1.96h4.544v1.975c0 .672.565 1.195 1.237 1.195h.018c.672 0 1.197-.523 1.197-1.195v-2.182c.598-.3.957-.898.957-1.586v-3.828c0-.99-.783-1.794-1.774-1.794zM7.189 12.107a.451.451 0 1 1 .902 0 .451.451 0 0 1-.902 0z"/></svg><br>
                  <b>Main 2A</b></span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item cat2">
            <div class="sub-list" data-for="cat2">
              <label class="sub-btn" for="hook">
                <input class="sub-input" id="hook" type="radio" name="radios"/>
                <span class="sub-icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25"><path
                    id=""
                    fill="silver"
                    d="M13.587 16.6h1.829c-.254 1.303-1.405 2.31-2.772 2.31a2.836 2.836 0 0 1-2.823-2.836v-5.166a.853.853 0 0 0 .25-.611V5.884a.779.779 0 0 0-.776-.793.779.779 0 0 0-.776.793v4.413c0 .246.1.466.25.611v5.166c0 2.115 1.74 3.835 3.854 3.835 2.09 0 3.821-1.717 3.846-3.83l.012-1.97v-1.573L13.587 16.6z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <br>
                  <b>Main 2B</b>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The color of the selected sub-item radio should change only to match the color of the associated main item.